# Target Highest Primary Key When Adding New Row to DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

So I have a DataGridView filled with data with the Primary Key being ex."Order Number". Whenever a new row is added to the DGV, I have this line of code added to target the new row.

```
dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = True
```

This works great and all, but whenever a user is sorted on a column header, this will go to the last row like it is supposed to do, but that's not where the new row is.

So is it possible for me to do this, but to target the highest primary key number? Since the newest row being added will contain the highest primary key number at the time of creation.

Thank you.

UPDATE: I have found a way to get the highest value of such primary key by using:

```
Dim MaxID = dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Max(Function(r) Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells("Order Number").Value))
```

But whenever I use:

```
dgv.Rows(MaxID).Selected = True
```

I get an error saying the value is outside the bounds of the array. I tried MaxID - 1 as well.

Comment: The value of the new PK isnt related to the number of rows - at least not with a proper DB-supplied AI PK.  So you want the row which has `MaxID` as the value

Comment: The row beforehand has a value of 100000, the new row being added is 100001, which is MaxID, but it blows up right as it is trying to select the MaxID.

Comment: You should know that there is more than one event which will fire when rows are added.  `userAddedRow` for instance will provide the actual row, which could then be selected.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get there:

```
    Dim qry = (From r As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgv1.Rows
               Order By r.Cells("Order Number").Value Descending
               Select r.Index)
    If qry.Any Then
        Dim idx As Integer = qry.First
        Me.dgv1.Rows(idx).Selected = True
    End If
```

Or you can directly select the row

```
    Dim targetRow = Me.dgv1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
        OrderByDescending(Function(r) r.Cells("Order Number").Value).FirstOrDefault
    If targetRow IsNot Nothing Then targetRow.Selected = True
```

Comment: Sadly I couldn't get either of these to work correctly. Most likely because the project that I am working on has been in development for years and I am new to the program itself, so I would probably have to trace down a lot of bad code and clean it up to get this to work properly.

Comment: That's odd, the code you figured out is already pretty similar. You can post how you adapted my examples and describe what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I had to resort to doing is by resetting the sort from the DataSet that was filling the DataGridView, and then select the row and currentcell.

```
    DataSet.Tables("TableName").DefaultView.Sort = ""
    dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = True
    dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(dgv.FirstDisplayedCell.ColumnIndex)
```

Definitely not the best fix, because I am resetting the sort before focusing on a row, but it will hold the users over for the time being.